# Flutter-upload a file to a specific folder in google drive

Tags: flutter, dart, file-upload, google-api, google-drive-api

Ive created an app that can upload a file to google drive using the drive api.I've got 2 functions. listing the files inside google drive and upload a file to google drive.

```
 Future<void> _listGoogleDriveFiles() async {
var list;
var client = GoogleAuthClient(authHeaders);
var ga = drive.DriveApi(client);
ga.files.list().then((value) {
  setState(() {
    list = value;
  });
  for (var i = 0; i < list.files.length; i++) {
    print("Id: ${list.files[i].id} File Name:${list.files[i].name}");
  }
});
}

Future<void> uploadToDrive() async {

final authenticateClient = GoogleAuthClient(authHeaders!);
final driveApi = drive.DriveApi(authenticateClient);
final Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
final File file1 = File('${directory.path}/my_file.txt');
file1.writeAsStringSync(jsonEncode(context.read<IdeaProvider>().ideaList));

try {
  var client = GoogleAuthClient(authHeaders);
  var ga = drive.DriveApi(client);
  drive.File fileToUpload = drive.File();
  fileToUpload.name = fileName;
  try {
    var response = await ga.files.create(
      fileToUpload,
      uploadMedia: drive.Media(file1.openRead(), file1.lengthSync()),
    );
    logger.wtf(response.id);
  } catch (e) {
    logger.w(e);
  }
} catch (e) {
  logger.e(e);
}
}
```

Right now the file get uploaded and the program lists all the files in drive. How can I create a folder and upload the file that specific folder and get the list of files just inside that folder?

Comment: Are you looking to create a new folder altogether or just use an existing folder?

Comment: use an existing folder